# Disable button when pdf message is empty

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I try to disable a button when A textfield(PDF) is empty. I try it like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div id="hideButtonProduct">
                <br /><br />  <a href="" disabled="@(mailModel.PdfMessage == null || mailModel.PdfMessage == string.Empty)" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGeneratePDF" name="btnGeneratePDF" formtarget="_blank" onclick="generatePdfPreview('GeneratePDFMailProductHandler'); return false;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"> </i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.PreviewPDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the button is still selecteble when there is no text in it.

Thank you

And this is the textbox:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "GeneratePDFMailProductHandler", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
        </div>
```

I try it like this:

```
   <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled", "disabled");

            $("#GeneratePDFMailProductHandler").on("keypress", function () {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

The problem if I do it like this:

@if (Model.PdfMessage == null || Model.PdfMessage == string.Empty) {


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter").prop("disabled", "disabled");

            $("#GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter").on("keypress", function () {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    $("#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#btnGeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter").prop("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
}
```

The button is always disabled. Even when there is text inside

This is my complete view:

```
@model SenecaFormsServer.Areas.Dashboard.Models.EditProductModel
@using SenecaFormsServer.Areas.Dashboard.Models
@using Seneca.SfsLib.Connectors

<div id="ConnectorSettings-MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS">


    <h4>@Resources.Entity.Product.SettingsForConnector: Mail product handlers</h4>

    @{
        MailProductHandlersModel mailModel = Model.ConnectorModels["MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS"] as MailProductHandlersModel;
    }



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.Sender, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Editor("MailProductHandlers_sender", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = mailModel.Sender, @placeholder = Model.CustomerConfig.DefaultSenderAddress } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.MailSubject, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Editor("MailProductHandlers_subject", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = mailModel.Subject } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Reply to form submitter", new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.CheckBox("MailProductHandlers_replytoFormSubmitter", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    -->

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.MailMessage, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.Message)
            @*@Html.TextArea("MailProductHandlers_message", mailModel.Message, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 15 })*@
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDF, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFYes) @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF,true, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF,false, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group" id="MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor">
        <div id="hideLableProduct">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.PdfMessage, new { @id = "hideLable", @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control tiny-mce", @id = "GeneratePDFMailProductHandler", data_lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => mailModel.PdfMessage)
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
        </div>
        @if (mailModel.PdfMessage == null || mailModel.PdfMessage == string.Empty) {

        }

        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div id="hideButtonProduct">
                <br /><br />  <a href=""  class="btn btn-success" id="btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler" name="btnGeneratePDF" formtarget="_blank" onclick="generatePdfPreview('GeneratePDFMailProductHandler'); return false;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"> </i> @Resources.Action.Navigation.PreviewPDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if (!mailModel.IscheckedPDF) {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_pdfeditor').hide();
        });     


    </script>
}

<script>



    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler").prop("disabled",true);

        $("#GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter").on("change",function () {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                $("#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler").prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $("#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The strange this is that if I keep the textfield blank and save then if you return to the textfield the button is disabled, but stays disabled, even you put text in it. But if you put some text in it and save and return then the button is enabled.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable button whenever a text field is empty dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled", true);

 $("#GeneratePDFMailProductHandler").on("change", function () {
   if ($(this).val() != "") {
     $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
     $("#btnGeneratePDF").prop("disabled",true);
       }
     });
});
```