# Disable button when no value in the input text

Tags: jquery

I need to disable the button when no value is inserted in the input text

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">             
        <p class="description">Please Enter Your Tracking Number.</p>

        <input type="text" id="tracking-input" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="Enter your Tracking number(s)"onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="register" class="full-width btn-medium">Track</button>
</form>
```

Have tried this but doesn't work

```
<script>

function buttonState(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            if($(this).val() == "" ) return false;
        $('#register').attr('disabled', '');
    })
}

$(function(){
    $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('input').change(buttonState);
})

</script>
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery disable/enable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

Comment: The mistake that im using <Button> on the form

Comment: This doesn't work as well

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val != ''){
            $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyup` event to check for `disabled` property of button based on the value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#register').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#tracking-input').keyup(function(){
        $('#register').prop('disabled', this.value === "");     
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
      <p class="description">Please Enter Your Tracking Number.</p>
      <input type="text" id="tracking-input" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="Enter your Tracking number(s)"onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
  </div> <br>
  <button type="submit" id="register" class="full-width btn-medium">Track</button>
</form>
```

Comment: just realized that code only work on the web version, but doesn't work on phone

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#register").prop("disabled",true);

$("#tracking-input").keyup(function(){
var valuee=$("#tracking-input").val().trim();
if(valuee==""){
$("#register").prop("disabled",true);

}else{
$("#register").prop("disabled",false);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <p class="description">Please Enter Your Tracking Number.</p>

                    <input type="text" id="tracking-input" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="Enter your Tracking number(s)">
                </div> <br>
                <button type="submit" id="register" class="full-width btn-medium">Track</button>
            </form>
```