# I need help making the submit button only appear when you have typed in the text box

Tags: php, html

I'm using html and I have a text box and I also have the submit button but I only want the button to appear when you have typed text into the text box. I also have a lot of php in my scripts you its fine if you do it with that.

I've tried different on click events and I've searched everywhere but i can't find anything. I know this is probably a simple question but I'm completely stuck.

```
<div class = "profileLeftSideContent">

<form action="<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">

<textarea id="post" name="post" rows="15" cols="40" placeholder="Bio goes 
here...">
</textarea>

<input id="buddon" type="submit" name="send" 
value="Save" style="background-color: #DCE5EE; border: 3px solid #666; 
color:#666; height: 65px; width: 73px;">

    </form>
</div>
```

I want the button named save to only appear when you have typed in the above text area. (note, there is more code than this and the text box and button show up fine normally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button whenever a text field is empty dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple:

```js
function ckField(){
  if($.trim($('#post').val()) == ""){
    $('#buddon').css('display', 'none');
  }else{
    $('#buddon').css('display', '');
  }
}

$('#post').keyup(function(){ ckField(); });

//initial state
ckField();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "profileLeftSideContent">

<form action="<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">

<textarea id="post" name="post" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Bio goes 
here...">
</textarea>

<input id="buddon" type="submit" name="send" 
value="Save" style="background-color: #DCE5EE; border: 3px solid #666; 
color:#666; height: 65px; width: 73px;">

    </form>
</div>
```

I reduced the textara rows to 5, for display reasons.

Comment: Sure, you want to make a function of it.  That way if your form is "sticky" retains data after a page reload, it will behave as expected.   It may not hurt to make the button `display:none` by default, which will prevent it from doing the flash, where it's there for DOM render then vanishes when JS kicks in.  `<input id="buddon" type="submit" name="send" value="Save" style="background-color: #DCE5EE; display:none; ...." />`  In other words just add `display:none` to the element.  The initial call to `ckField();` will show it if it needs to be shown.