# Disable Button isn't working properly. Text are remove but button is still enabled

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where if I remove the numbers from the textbooks, the submit button is still enabled. At first, when I key in my inputs on the textbox, it enables my button, but if I remove one of it, it is still enabled.

This is my  for my button. I've set the id of my textboxes are "digit" and "digit1"

```js
if ((document.getElementById("digit").value > 0) && (document.getElementById("digit1").value > 0)) {
  rand.removeAttribute('disabled');
} else {
  rand.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

```html
<input id="rand" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: You didn't define `rand`

Comment: @Spectric rand is the id for my button

Comment: You didn't define `rand` within the two <script> tags. Could you show us how you defined it?

Comment: use `document.getElementById("rand").disabled = true/false`

Comment: why you use input except normal button tag ? from seo point of view this is not good.

Comment: @Spectric ohhh can I define rand like this? document.getElementById("rand").removeAttribute('disabled');

Comment: @noor `disabled` (you forgot the last "d" :))

Comment: Your question is missing details. What is `digit`? What is `digit1`?

Comment: Click "Run code snippet". [Edit] the question until there are no more errors and the question reproduces the problem you are seeing.

Comment: @Spectric https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431408/button-cant-be-enable-and-error-message-not-prompt,  take a look at my problem for me please, and you will know where the digit and digit1 come from

Comment: @NgLengPoh Alright. Please include those in your question.

Comment: This question is already answered here, take a look: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for, please check this once:
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically)

Comment: "but if I remove one of it, it is still enabled" ... Not sure if I understand correctly, but you are comparing if `digit` and `digit1` values are `> 0`. Have you tried OR `||` instead of `&&` ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly define the variable `random`.

```js
function validate(){
var rand = document.getElementById("rand");
if ((document.getElementById("digit").value > 0) && (document.getElementById("digit1").value > 0)) {
  rand.removeAttribute('disabled');
} else {
  rand.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">  
<form action="random" method="get" onSubmit="return validate()">
        <tr>
            <td>
            Lowest number: 
            <input id="digit" type="text" name="lowestnumber" onchange="validate(event)">
            <span id="numbers"></span>
            <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Highest number:
            <input id="digit1" type="text" name="highestnumber" onchange="validate(event)">  
            <span id="numbers1"></span>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="rand" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" disabled><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br/>
</form>
</table>
```

Since stacksnippets.net is currently down, you can view the live fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/41xgLjw9/

Comment: I just realised that it is the if else that is causing the button not to be disabled if no text is inside, how do I solve it?

Comment: @NgLengPoh In the fiddle, the button is disabled if there is no text inside.

Comment: yes I understand, but I think the problem is that I have too many if else statement. If it is just the if else statement for the button, it will work