# Disable search button when there is no input

Tags: php, html, search-box

This is my search box

```
     <div id="search1"  style="margin:0;">
        <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"  method="get">
          <input class="search-pishrafte1" name="s" value="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" type="text">
          <input class="searchsubmit" value="" type="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
```

right now if i click on submit it will search for text:"search"
I want to disable it , i dont want the button to work when user didnt type anything

I tried this : [Disable button whenever a text field is empty dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067005/disable-button-whenever-a-text-field-is-empty-dynamically)
but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using **jQuery**, I coded with `hide()` and `show()` functions
So will show button after `input` text or deleted button if `empty` input

I have code like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchsubmit').hide();
  $('input[type="text"].search-pishrafte1').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('.searchsubmit').show();
    } else {
      $('.searchsubmit').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

And deleted your code in:

```
onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"
```

**Here example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.searchsubmit').hide();
  $('input[type="text"].search-pishrafte1').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('.searchsubmit').show();
    } else {
      $('.searchsubmit').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search1" style="margin:0;">
  <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
    <input class="search-pishrafte1" name="s" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    <input class="searchsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

## UPDATED

I'm added if using a javascript with `disabled` function.
Here is code for javascript:

```
let button = document.getElementById("search-btn")
let input = document.getElementById("input-search")

input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
if(input.value.length == 0) {
  button.disabled = true
 } else {
  button.disabled = false
 }
})
```

In this code need `addEventListener` into `input` for detect `input` if typing

```js
let button = document.getElementById("search-btn")
let input = document.getElementById("input-search")
input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    if(input.value.length == 0) {
    button.disabled = true
  } else {
    button.disabled = false
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="search1"  style="margin:0;">
        <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"  method="get">
          <input id="input-search" class="search-pishrafte1" name="s" placeholder="Search" type="text" required="required" />
          <input id="search-btn" class="searchsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit" disabled>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Then if you want *if i click on submit it will search for text:"search" I want to disable it*. You need a changed a `value` in `input` to `placeholder`.

Comment: Don't need to use jQuery to prevent the form submit if the input isn't filled. You just need to define that the input is `required` and remove the  `value` attribute, because if you define a input `value`, the input will be filled with this data. And your code is submiting the form on pressing `ENTER` even if the submit button is hidden which doesn't prevent the form submition.

Comment: @WilliamCarneiro Sorry I don't seen your comment, First of all I only provide answers according to questions " _i dont want the button to work when user didnt type anything_". So I give it with `jQuery`. You also need to read the questions understandably. If it's still in context, remove the words `Don't need to use jQuery`.

Comment: @Adhitya I understood the question, and what I saw is that the submit button is working because the value of the input is filled by the `value` attribute (which seems that must be the `placeholder` attribute instead), so you relly **don't need to use javascript or jQuery library to prevent the form button from submiting the form.* Even if "it's still in context", you're giving a wrong way to work with forms, and as I said, your solution don't prevent form submitiion on press `ENTER`, the only thing that happens is that the button is hidden, which don't prevent anything.

Comment: Here is question _Disable search button when there is no input_. So the submit button will still work. Because what he needs is removing the button if he doesn't make input.

Answer (score -1):

You're using the `value` attribute incorrectly. If you define the `value` attribute, the submit button will send the form because the input is already filled.

Replace the attribute `value` to `placeholder`, and don't forget to define that the input is `required`, like this:

```
<input class="search-pishrafte1" name="s" placeholder="Search" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" type="text" required="required" />
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , I used this but still is searching for "search"